# ipython-sql: How to connect hive/presto with connect_args?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython-magic

Note: I posted the question at https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql/issues/149

I can connect hive/presto using `create_engine` like this

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
conn = create_engine(
    'presto://user@host:port',
    connect_args={'protocol': 'https',
                  'requests_kwargs': {
    'auth': HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pw'),
    'verify': '/cert.pem',
    }}
)
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM dw.my_table", conn)
```

However, if I use `ipython-sql`, how should I connect?

From the doc, it seems only support string passed to `create_engine`, something like this

```
%%sql postgresql://will:longliveliz@localhost/shakes
select * from character
where abbrev = 'ALICE
```

How can I specify additional configs in `connect_args`?

Answer (score 0):

ipython-sql does not support this, as it expects a connection string. However, you can use [JupySQL](https://github.com/ploomber/jupysql) (an actively maintained fork that keeps 100% compatibility).

You can do something like this:

```py
%%sql conn
select * from character
where abbrev = 'ALICE
```

[Documentation](https://jupysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html?create-connection-with-existing-engine#create-connection-with-existing-engine)